# Passing parameters to scalameta paradise macro

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scalameta

I am trying to create a macro annotation but I need to pass it parameters.

```
class ToPojo(param1: String, param2: String) extends StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
        ...
  }
}
```

which is used as

```
@ToPojo("p1", "p2")
case class Entity(a: Int, m: Map[Long, Boolean])
```

The problem with above code is that the `Entity` gets to the `apply` as `defn` already with the annotation stripped - hence I can not get the parameters from there. Also the `param1` and `param2` fields are not accessible from the `apply` method since it gets inlined.

Could you please point me to the easiest way to overcome this using scala meta? I thought about using two annotations

```
@ToPojo
@ToPojoParams("p1", "p2")
case class Entity(a: Int, m: Map[Long, Boolean])
```

But thats hacky and ugly.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the ScalaMeta Paradise description under  [How do I pass an argument to the macro annotation?](http://scalameta.org/paradise/#HowdoIpassanargumenttothemacroannotation?) section

> You match on `this` as a Scalameta tree

```
package scalaworld.macros

import scala.meta._

class Argument(arg: Int) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    // `this` is a scala.meta tree.
    println(this.structure)
    val arg = this match {
      // The argument needs to be a literal like `1` or a string like `"foobar"`.
      // You can't pass in a variable name.
      case q"new $_(${Lit.Int(arg)})" => arg
      // Example if you have more than one argument.
      case q"new $_(${Lit.Int(arg)}, ${Lit.String(foo)})" => arg
      case _ => ??? // default value
    }
    println(s"Arg is $arg")
    defn.asInstanceOf[Stat]
  }
}
```

Note that this code is a bit naive and doesn't handle named arguments. If you have many arguments, writing all possible combinations of usual and named arguments is boring. So you may try something like this:

```
package examples

import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.meta._

class MyMacro(p1: String, p2: Int) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {


  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    val params = Params.extractParams(this)
    //some implementation
    ... 
  }

}


case class Params(p1: String, p2: Int) {
  def update(name: String, value: Any): Params = name match {
    case "p1" => copy(p1 = value.asInstanceOf[String])
    case "p2" => copy(p2 = value.asInstanceOf[Int])
    case _ => ???
  }
}

object Params {
  private val paramsNames = List("p1", "p2")

  def extractParams(tree: Stat): Params = {
    val args: immutable.Seq[Term.Arg] = tree.asInstanceOf[Term.New].templ.parents.head.asInstanceOf[Term.Apply].args

    args.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Params(null, 0))((acc, argAndIndex) => argAndIndex._1 match {
      case q"${Lit(value)}" => acc.update(paramsNames(argAndIndex._2), value)
      case q"${Term.Arg.Named(name, Lit(value))}" => acc.update(name.value, value)
    })
  }
}
```